# Is there a way to echo an alias?

Tags: command-line, alias

I have set some aliases in my .bashrc file and for some reason one of them does not behave as expected.

Since I don't remember the exact command assigned to that alias, I would like to see the command to find out what's wrong.

Except the obvious opening the .bashrc file to see it, is there a command that just echos the command assigned to that alias?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Instead of using `grep`, you can just type `alias aliasname` to see what an alias is set to.

For example, `alias ls` will return `ls='ls --color=auto'`.

Also take a look at the `type` and `whence` commands, which return more detailed information about utilities, including executable files in your path, shell built-ins, aliases, and shell functions.

Comment: Excellent :) I missed where TS said to know the alias name :) +1

Comment: Remember to surround your alias name with quotes, otherwise it might not work.

Answer (score 10):

It is as simple as typing

```
alias
```

on command line. This will list ALL aliases so if you know specifics you can grep that like so ..

```
alias|grep rm
```

to find commands that use `rm` where you can substitute `rm` for anything `alias` would show you to find that specific alias.

Answer (score 1):

```
which rm
```

may be the most useful.  Normally, it just shows the full path of executable as found in your $PATH.  If there are multiple executables of that name, it shows the first one found (the one that would be executed).  If there is an alias, it shows the alias in addition to the path.

```
whereis rm
```

can also help figure out things like this.  While `which` shows the first instance found in $PATH, `whereis` shows them all.